# What does "public" mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, encapsulation, public

I understand that `internal` means that the property can only be accessed by the Swift code, and `private` means that the property can only be accessed by that file, but doesn't `public` basically mean the same thing as `internal`? What other than the Swift script would want to access the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Public access enables entities to be used within any source file from
>   their defining module, and also in a source file from another module
>   that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when
>   specifying the public interface to a framework.
>
> Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file
>   from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining
>   source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of
>   a specific piece of functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Answer (score 1):

Public is accessible anywhere in that module, and accessible in the source of another module that implements the module (i.e. importing a file with public variables allows the importer to access the public variables, but not internal or private variables)